# Converting a pdf to an image with gsdll32.dll and security issue

Tags: asp.net, pdf, converters, ghostscript

i use gsdll32.dll this library to convert pdf to image. everything works file in my machine but when i upload everything in our hosting web server to ORCSWEB then problem start. a exception generated for security & permission relation when i call routine from gsdll32.dll.

so i just need to know is there any way out as a result no exception will occur and pdf will be converted to image. how could i solve this permission & security issue without talking any help from ORCSWEB tech support because ORCSWEB tech support said they could not change any security setting for shared location hosting. our site is hosted in ORCSWEB shared location.can i do anything from my coding site to resolve this issue.

is there any equivalent .net assembly (Pure manage code) library which i can use to convert pdf to image. please give some insight. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only imagine an issue with the trust level. Is your application in medium trust? You can check it by using the code in the answer of this SO post: [How to determine if the current application is Medium Trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325354/how-to-determine-if-the-current-application-is-medium-trust)

According to the answer of this question: [Can GhostScript run in Medium Trust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699207/can-ghostscript-run-in-medium-trust) GhostScript won't work in medium trust.